# How to append first row data while creating new sheets dynamically in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this code that creates new sheets dynamically but leaves out the first row because its structured such that it creates new sheets based on values in the first column **A:A**. How do I structure it to capture the first (title row) before appending the rest of data.

```
function newSheet() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var templateSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("main")
    var getNames = [...new Set(sheet1.getRange("A2:A").getValues().filter(String).toString().split(","))];
var title = sheet1.getRange("A1:Z1").getValues().filter(String).toString().split(",");// Not sure


    for (var i = 0; i < getNames.length; i++) {
        var copy = ss.getSheetByName(getNames[i]);
             if (copy) {

        ss.deleteSheet(copy)


                 var rowIndexes = sheet1.getRange("A:A").getValues()
                .map((value, index) => [value[0], (index + 1)])
                .filter(value => value[0] === getNames[i]);


            var namedSheet = ss.insertSheet(getNames[i]);

            rowIndexes.map(index => {
                var rowValues = sheet1.getRange(index[1], 1, 1, sheet1.getLastColumn()).getValues();
                sheet1.getLastColumn()).getValues();;

                // Append title row first???

                namedSheet.appendRow(rowValues[0]);

            ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(getNames[i]));
            ss.moveActiveSheet(ss.getNumSheets());

            });
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve, specially this: `How do I structure it to capture the first row statically?`. Could you please expand on this? Maybe sharing a sanitized copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, containing some explanation on the desired outcome, could be useful.

Comment: @Iamblichus, Thanks for your response. what this code does is look for column A2: A and get the values to use as a new sheet name. When the sheet is created, all raw data that has the same name in column A is copied to the new sheet. I would like as this happens in the first row, which doesn't change is copied first to every new sheet created. I have edited my question. I hope its more clearer

Comment: @Iamblichus  any chance you got an idea?

Comment: I just posted an answer. Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Situation:

You want to do the following:

- Create a new sheet for each different value in column A (if it was previously created, delete it).
- The first row in each created sheet should be like the first row in the source sheet (`main`).
- The rest of the sheet should contain only the rows in which column A value matches the sheet name.

#### Code sample (check inline comments):

```js
function newSheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var templateSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("main");
  var getFirstColumn = sheet1.getRange(2, 1, sheet1.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().map(row => row[0]); // Get column A contents (excluding row 1)
  var getNames = [...new Set(getFirstColumn)]; // Get unique values from column A (excluding row 1)
  var title = sheet1.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet1.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]; // Get row 1 values
  var data = sheet1.getRange(2, 1, sheet1.getLastRow() - 1, sheet1.getLastColumn()).getValues(); // Get all data in "main" sheet (excluding row 1)
  for (var i = 0; i < getNames.length; i++) { // Iterate through each unique value in column A
    var copy = ss.getSheetByName(getNames[i]);
    if (copy) ss.deleteSheet(copy); // If there is a sheet with this name, delete it
    var filteredData = data.filter(row => row[0] === getNames[i]); // Get rows from "main" sheet with current unique column A value
    var namedSheet = ss.insertSheet(getNames[i]); // Create sheet for current unique column A value
    namedSheet.appendRow(title); // Append row 1 values to new sheet
    namedSheet.getRange(2, 1, filteredData.length, filteredData[0].length).setValues(filteredData); // Copy filtered data to new sheet
  }
}
```

#### Notes:

- There is no need to get the indexes of the rows to copy, you can just filter them accordingly without keeping the indexes. This simplifies your code significantly.
- You can just append the first row before appending the rest of data to the sheet. You could also add the `title` array to the beginning of `filteredData` array and write all data at the same time, including first row.

Comment: Thanks @Iamblichus. This really clear and the fact that fewer lines of codes does the entire task work is amazing.